# How do I Bulk Send a Template using the API?

Tags: docusignapi

I followed this guide:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/bulk-send-envelopes/

For Step 4. I removed the Documents property and used a TemplateId instead and got the following error:

`Error calling CreateEnvelope: {"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER", "message":"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. 'recipients' may not be specified when template Id is set. use templateRoles'."}`

The issue is `CreateBulkSendList`[(Bulk Envelopes API)](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/bulkenvelopes/bulksend/createbulksendlist/) doesnt allow for TemplateRoles(Step 3. from the guide)

Not sure how to proceed, in fewer words:
Id like to Bulk send an envelope using Template Roles

I could write a loop and have it send 1 by 1 instead of Bulk but id rather not.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that roles are used in multiple ways with templates and bulk send. If you have a template that uses "placeholder" recipients, meaning that they only have a role, but not a specific email/name assigned to them, then you will first have to create an envelope with these following the guide on [how to create an envelope from a template](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote/) (which requires the use of `templateRoles` object instead of `recipients` object). Then you use this envelope and continue from step 5 if this how-to.